# How can I ignore files with dartanalyzer?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I want to ignore all files ending with .g.dart, .inject.dart, .inject.summary in bin/ lib/ and test/

What is the syntax to ignore files `dartanalyzer`? I tried adding this section to my analysis_options.yaml file:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/**.g.dart
```

to my analysis_options.yaml and when I run `dartanalyzer` on my project it doesn't take that in consideration. I also tried using `dartanalyzer --options analysis_options.yaml` to make sure it'd use these options without luck.

The only syntax that I found would work with `dartanalyzer` cli tool was:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - **/*.g.dart
```

but IntelliJ says it's an error (`Undefined alias`.)

if I use this syntax:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/**.g.dart
    - lib/**.inject.dart
    - lib/**.inject.summary
    - test/**.g.dart
    - test/**.inject.dart
```

The analyzer embedded in IntelliJ filters correctly those files, but the `dartanalyzer` cli tool doesn't.

Is there any way that works both with IntelliJ and the `dartanalyzer` CLI tool?

Note:

I'm using

```
❯ dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.4.0 (Wed Jun 19 11:53:45 2019 +0200) on "linux_x64"
```

Comment: Well there's [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25551) on dartanalyzer about that. It's a known problem for a long time.

Comment: @Muldec points to the right issue you might want to promote that to an answer. This isn't solvable today. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34069 is another issue discussing at a higher level the desire for different analysis in generated code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you can see in the docs (https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) the correct syntax of excluding files from analyzer is:

```yaml
include: package:very_good_analysis/analysis_options.yaml
analyzer:
  exclude: [build/**, lib/**.freezed.dart, lib/**.g.dart]
```

Comment: you could emphasize the difference from the example the OP gave because it might not be obvious at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

Well there's [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25551) on dartanalyzer about that. It's a known problem for a long time and won't be solved anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Below version works for me in both AndroidStudio and dart cli. Below code is snippet from `analysis_options.yaml`

```
include: package:very_good_analysis/analysis_options.yaml
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/gen/**
```

This exclude all files from lib/gen folder as they are generated files and we don't own them.

As you can see, we are using `very_good_analysis` which is defined in pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
  very_good_analysis: ^5.1.0
```

Below is mine flutter and dart versions

```
Flutter Version:  3.19.1
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6
```